Could not load Krabsetw in C# .NET 6.0
I am using C# with the .NET 6.0 framework in Windows 10 and trying to use the NuGet Microsoft.O365.Security.Native.ETW package, corresponding to the Microsoft Krabsetw library, which allows the use of ETW. This is the repository on GitHub: https://github.com/microsoft/krabsetw. NuGet page: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.O365.Security.Native.ETW/
Although all the dependencies are resolved and the library is installed correctly, at run it says that it cannot load the library. This is the exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80070002
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.O365.Security.Native.ETW, Version=1.0.8668.31639, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.
  Source=MyProject

Inspecting the library dependencies, in the folder where it has been compiled, I can see that ijwhost.dll is not found.

Although the dependency is located in the same directory, in the following path: runtimes\win-x64\native\Ijwhost.dll
This is the directory bin\Debug\net6.0-windows7.0 structure:

[My project files]
Microsoft.O365.Security.Native.ETW.dll
runtimes\win-x64\native

Ijwhost.dll



If I change the .NET framework version to 5.0, everything works fine. Above 6.0, it does not work with any version. Any ideas?

I also reproduced the same problem. It may be an issue, I noticed that you have posted the same problem in GitHub. I recommend that you could continue to follow that case. And if it is an issue in fact, you could post an answer here to tell others who may face the similar issues. link: https://github.com/microsoft/krabsetw/issues/238

@JackJJun thank you very much for reproducing the problem. At first, I was getting crazy thinking it might be a problem with me or my environment. If I find a solution or answer from the developers, I will post it here as well.

look forward to your update.

@swannman answered the issue in the repository on GitHub: https://github.com/microsoft/krabsetw/issues/238
Including Ijwhost.dll in the root of the bin directory fixes this. It can be automated by adding the following to the project properties:
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.O365.Security.Native.ETW" Version="4.3.2">
      <GeneratePathProperty>true</GeneratePathProperty>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="CopyFiles" AfterTargets="Build">
    <ItemGroup>
      <File Include="$(PkgMicrosoft_O365_Security_Native_ETW)\runtimes\win-x64\native\Ijwhost.dll"></File>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(File)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)"></Copy>
  </Target>

Maybe it is not the prettiest way, but in my case this has allowed me to solve the issue.
